# How to check in a 2-Dimensional Array if one element is followed by the same element n number of times

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm creating this project for my CS class that mimics a Tic Tac Toe Board. It worked fine for the original 3x3 square but now I need to make the program ask the user how big of a board they want it to be. It can only be a 3x3 to 14x14 square in size. I also am asking how many connections or how many X's or O's in a row they want to win the game. The connection can only be equal to or less than the size but not less than 3.

For the condition that checked for horizontal x's or o's in a row originally looked like this,

```
for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
  for(int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
    if(board[r][c] == Cell.X && board[r][c + 1] == Cell.X && board[r][c + 2] == Cell.X) {
        return GameStatus.X_WON;
    }
    else if(board[r][c] == Cell.O && board[r][c + 1] == Cell.O && board[r][c + 2] == Cell.O) {
        return GameStatus.O_WON;
    }
  }
}
```

I have gotten the program to take inputs for the connections and board size called,

```
int connections;
SuperTicTacToe.getSize();
```

I wrote this out this,

```
private GameStatus isWinner() {
  int count = 0;
  for(int r = 0; r < SuperTicTacToe.getSize(); r++) {
    for(int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
      for(int i = 0; i < connections; i++){
        if(board[r][c + i] == Cell.X ){
           count++;
        }
        if(count == connections){
           return GameStatus.X_WON;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the only thing I cannot seem to do is get the program to somehow check **In a row** there is connection number of x's or o's there. It only seems to check if there is **connection** number of x's on the board and not count anything in the last column.

Is there a way to check in a row if an element is equal to the same element in front of it **n** number of times?

Comment: Take a moment to think about what `for(int c = 0; c < 1; ++c) { ...}` actually means.  Hint: it's basically the same as `{int c = 0; {...}}`!  So you're not giving `c` a chance to advance along each row.  So you can find a connection if it starts at cell 0, but you never check for connections that start further in.

Comment: @Steven Villarreal please mark my answer as correct, or notify me of which requirements my answer does not reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always good to draw out the method you would use to solve this problem as a person, before writing down the code. If you've ever been taught code in a class, you know how important whiteboards are.

```
// This program pretends board is a boolean[][] array
boolean horizontalFlag = true; // Assume that it is a 3 in a row
boolean verticalFlag = true; // If it is proven not to be, then change to false
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        if(!(board[i][j])) verticalFlag = false; // These methods draw horizontal and vertical lines
        if(!(board[j][i])) horizontalFlag = false; //i.e.
    }
}
/* What the code does, visualized.
Horizontal check = h vertical check = v both = b none = 0
This is based on each iteration of i.
 i=0   i=1   i=2
b h h|0 v 0|0 0 v
v 0 0|h b h|0 0 v
v 0 0|0 v 0|h h b
*/
if(board[1][1]) { // Diagonals
    if(board[0][0] && board[2][2]) return true; 
    if(board[2][0] && board[0][2]) return true; 
}
if(horizontalFlag||verticalFlag) return true; // If the flags "say" that there are straight lines
```

Note that this code is not directly compatible with your program.

Comment: I'd rather say pen and paper, or Excel and a formula! ;) But of course the most important part of programming is to understand your algorithm (and of course to type it correctly into your compiler-window)!

Comment: Yes, of course. The logic of the code is what people struggle to create and improve, but typing and translating (to another coding language) is much easier.